# Use of Itô isometry for correlation calculation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

When calculating the covariance of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process#Formulas_for_moments_of_nonstationary_processes) article applies implicitly the Itô isometry with the fact of non-overlapping independent increments of the Wiener process in the following step:
$$
\sigma^2 e^{-\theta (s+t)}\,\mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^s  e^{\theta u}\, \mathrm{d}W_u \int_0^t  e^{\theta v}\, \mathrm{d}W_v \right] 
= \frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta} \, e^{-\theta (s+t)}(e^{2\theta \min(s,t)}-1)
$$
Could someone explain me how is this exactly done, step by step? More generally, how does one apply the Itô isometry to these two processes?
$$
\mathbb{E}  \left[ \int_0^s f(u)\,\mathrm{d} W_u \int_0^t g(v) \,\mathrm{d} W_v \right]
$$